# bulk update data into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have below data in stored in my db.

```
[
    {
        date:'1-1-2016',
        users:[
            {
                'name':'james',
                'age':18
            },
            {
                'name':'alice',
                'age':20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date:'2-1-2016',
        users:[
            {
                'name':'james',
                'age':18
            },
            {
                'name':'alice',
                'age':20
            },
            {
                'name':'xiaomi',
                'age':29
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have a challenge to bulk update array of object efficiently.

My initial solution to update on single collection is

```
Users.update({date:'1-1-2016','user.name':'james'},{'$set':'users.$.age':5}})
```

So this will update james's age to 5 from 18, base on date and user's name.

But how to bulk update, says a range of date is given? use loop with above query? I think it's not efficient. Need guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$gte`/`$gt` and `$lte`/`$lt` to match a date range:

```
db.users.update({
    date: {
        $gte: '1-1-2016',
        $lt: '31-1-2016'
    },
    'users.name': 'james'
}, { '$set': { 'users.$.age': 10 } }, { 'multi': true })
```

To bulk update with many couple of conditions name/age :

```
var data = [{ "name": "james", "age": 10 }, { "name": "alice", "age": 11 }];

var query = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    query.push({
        updateMany: {
            "filter": {
                date: {
                    $gte: '1-1-2016',
                    $lt: '31-1-2016'
                },
                'users.name': data[i].name
            },
            "update": { '$set': { 'users.$.age': data[i].age } }
        }
    })
}

db.users.bulkWrite(query);
```

Comment: what if on 1-1-2016 I want to set age to 10 on james and on 2-1-2016 I want to set age to 11 on james and so on? It's not date range sorry, I missed interpreted it. It's bulk update data on few different dates.

Comment: I've updated with `bulkWrite` to perform several `updateMany` based on a  dynamic configuration name/age

Comment: this is exactly what I've done earlier. But your logic has flaw, what if user selected 1-1-2016, 4-1-2016, and 1-2-2016?